# Why can't I craft TNT on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm using the Minecraft Server program to run a server for myself and a friend. I have all the ingredients for TNT, and I'm putting them together correctly, but it's not producing anything in the crafting window. Making TNT works fine in a single player game.

Is there some kind of server setting I need to change?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of how the crafting window looks when you try? Also, more than once have I been confused and switched the gunpowder with the sand, but I assume you've double checked that :)

Comment: added a screenshot!

Comment: Looks like an antigriefer policy in the works...

Comment: Are you using something like Bukkit? What are the plugins installed on your server?

Comment: There's no plugins or mods installed. I'm using a totally vanilla copy of Minecraft and the Minecraft Server.

Comment: @victoriah: Is it one of the snapshots?  Could be a bug.

Comment: No, it's a regular public release version

Comment: You got it from [here](https://minecraft.net/download), right? Not some sketchy website you found via Google? And you have no client mods? No TMI or NEI?

Comment: If you hover on the sand blocks the tooltip says "Sand", right?

Comment: Right. It says sand, gunpowder. I got both programs (Minecraft and Minecraft server) from the Minecraft website within the past week. No mods or edits at all. I'm a Minecraft noob, I don't even know how to do those things.

Comment: @victoriah Have you reinstalled minecraft yet?

Comment: Yes. I updated the server and my minecraft .exe to the new versions and it still doesn't work. So sad.

Answer (score 2):

You entered an incorrect damage value for that 64 stack of gunpowder you spawned for yourself via the op /give command.  Its gunpowder by name only, wont work in any crafting as it isnt natural gunpowder.

Go get them the real way, or next time don't use the fourth parameter of `/give <name> <itemid> [quantity] [dmg value]`

Comment: I didn't spawn them. I got them all from killing Creepers. As such this answer is completely useless.